# Is there a convenient way to set default values for ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings using a settings file?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using the built in settings infrastructure in my Windows Phone 8.1 application to store my settings key-value pairs. For instance:

```
ApplicationDataContainer settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
object value = settings.Values["DailyReminderOnOff"];
```

I'm trying to find a way to supply default values that come canned with the app at installation. Is there some recommended and convenient way of doing that?

I could implement my own system by placing a dirty bit and reading from a file if it's unset or provide defaults through if-null checks within the getter; but I'd rather avoid the hassle of writing and maintaining that code if the system provides something I've missed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default way to get the value. Why don't you use simple fallback like this:

```
const string DefaultValue1 = "value123";
object value = settings.Values["DailyReminderOnOff"] ?? DefaultValue1;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is probably what I'll end up going with then. I wanted a settings file because I find it more convenient to look through and I like the idea of being able to change some settings around without having to recompile the app. I can see how recompiling might not be a big deal if the apps needs to be repackaged anyway...but would've been a nice-to-have.